# Disabling Maplex in particular layer of data frame?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, maplex

I'm using ESRI ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1.
I am using Maplex (labeling extention) for designing map layout. But at some layer of Data frame, i need to be use standard label engine.

Is there a method for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method for doing this.

The labeling engine used is a property of the data frame.

The layers within a data frame do not have properties for setting layer-specific labeling engines.

Answer (score -2):

You can convert labels to annotation (in the map or a database) and place labels interactively.

Right click on the layer you'd like labels for, and select "Convert Labels to Annotation":

[image: Anno Menu 1]

A dialog box will open that will give you options to create labels in the map, or in a database.  It also gives you options to save all labels, labels in the current extent, or labels of selected features:

[image: Anno Menu 2]

A database is useful if you plan to use the labels in other maps.  Storing the annotation in the map is useful if this will be your only map that you need them in.  If saved in the map, the labels are converted to text that can be moved independently of the other labels, by hand.